# Как импортировать виртуальную машину linux redhat на windows virtualbox?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, kvm

Мне нужно развернуть виртуальную машину на windows. Мне скинули архив с образом жесткого диска и файл ovf. При импорте выдает ошибку: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004), ругается на элемент "disk". Если попробовать создать виртуальную машину и выбрать для него существующий жесткий диск выдает ошибку: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005), Could not get the storage format of the medium 'здесь путь' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
Образы жесткого диска лежит в папке images и они без расширения.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRudV.png

Comment: В виртуалке есть чё-то ценное\секретное\приватное\корпоративное?

Comment: @donRumata Думаю да, это образ сервера

Comment: Ну а ошибку в яндекс вбивать пробовал? Эту ссылку видел? http://forum.oszone.net/post-2723385.html